# get all preg_match_all matches recursively?

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to parse some attributes from a string. I am using the function below, which is working fine but I would like to parse all nested matches, right now it is only parsing the root level when the goal is to parse all the matches even the ones contained inside others:

```
function get_all_attributes( $tag, $text ){
    preg_match_all( '/\[(\[?)(embed|wp_caption|caption|gallery|playlist|audio|video|acf|page|row|column|loop\-grid|loop\-grid\-item|grid\-filters|page\-title|page\-section|header|header\-column|header\-menu|header\-logo)(?![\w-])([^\]\/]*(?:\/(?!\])[^\]\/]*)*?)(?:(\/)\]|\](?:([^\[]*+(?:\[(?!\/\2\])[^\[]*+)*+)\[\/\2\])?)(\]?)/s', $text, $matches );
    $out = array();

    if( isset( $matches[2] ) )
    {
        foreach( (array) $matches[2] as $key => $value )
        {
            if( $tag === $value ){
                $out[] = array(
                    'name' => $tag,
                    'attributes' => shortcode_parse_atts( $matches[3][$key] ),
                    'content' => trim($matches[5][$key]),
                );
            }
        }
    }

    return $out;
}
```

The following is the string being parsed, it contains shortcodes from Wordpress, which I am trying to put it in array to easily get the attributes later on:

```
[page key="2298"]
[page-title key="1446986321457"]aaaa[/page-title]
[page-title key="1446986418207"]bbbbb[/page-title]
[row key="1446893994674"]
    [column key="1446893994674_1"]              
        [image key="1446893994674_1_logo"]ccc[/image]
    [/column]
[/row]
```

Is it possible to get all strings both parents and children in the same array maybe using a recursive regex?

Comment: Not with regex it self, but by making your function recursive you could.

This is a perfect place to use XML though, why are you reinventing the xml parser?

Comment: I think it is possible (since PHP regex supports recursion), but I doubt it will be effecient. Use a BBCode parser, e.g. [jBBCode](http://jbbcode.com/).

Comment: @MiDri Do you mean parsing the shortcodes with xml_parse? I would expect it to only parse XML format, can it be used to parse shortcodes type of format?

Comment: Not sure if you can tell xml parse to use [] instead of <> but you could easily preparse the file and replace [ with < and ] with > and then use xml_parse.

Comment: @stribizhev I am actually trying not to use third party libraries. Would it be efficient if I only execute the function once storing about 20 matches on average in an array for later use (using PHP recursion)?

Comment: @MiDri I am not sure how much "pre-parsing" I would need to do, since with shortcodes there are "tags" which don't close itself, so I would be forced to check if they close later in the string and adding new closing tags, etc...?

Comment: oh you're right, did not notice that. Would require a bit more work in that case.

Comment: Actually, I wonder if Wordpress Shortcodes are based on BBcode, since they look very similar.